# double for loop not rendering from my function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying a double nested for loop but it's not quite unraveling how I predict, advice? am i not allowed to call a double for loop in function? Essentially it suppose to create a navbar from an array of objects i.e [{name:['Jonathan,'bob']},{dob:['may 21','june 22']}]

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

export function navBar(content){
  return(
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
    <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="me-auto">
        {content.map((cont) => {
                                  <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id={Object.keys(cont)[0]}>
                                      {
                                        Object.values(cont).map((key)=>{<a href={"http://localhost:3000/"+key}>{key}</a>})
                                        }
                                  </NavDropdown>
                                  })}
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning from your map functions:

```js
<Nav className='me-auto'>
  {content.map((cont) => {
    // from here
    <NavDropdown title='Dropdown' id={Object.keys(cont)[0]}>
      {Object.values(cont).map((key) => {
        // and from here
        <a href={'http://localhost:3000/' + key}>{key}</a>;
      })}
    </NavDropdown>;
  })}
</Nav>
```

Solution:

```js
<Nav className='me-auto'>
  {content.map((cont) => {
    return (<NavDropdown title='Dropdown' id={Object.keys(cont)[0]}>
      {Object.values(cont).map((key) => {
        return <a href={'http://localhost:3000/' + key}>{key}</a>;
      })}
    </NavDropdown>);
  })}
</Nav>;
```

Since you are using arrow functions, you can omit the curly brackets and the return:

```js
<Nav className='me-auto'>
  {content.map((cont) => (
    <NavDropdown title='Dropdown' id={Object.keys(cont)[0]}>
      {Object.values(cont).map((key) => (
        <a href={'http://localhost:3000/' + key}>{key}</a>
      ))}
    </NavDropdown>
  ))}
</Nav>;
```

Also, the `content` parameter of your `navBar` is not an array but the `props` object, so you shouldn't be able to call map on it.

If you use `navBar` like: `<navBar content={...}/>`, you have to update its code like:

```js
export function navBar({ content }){
  // ...
}
```